# How to connect to a Azure storage account blob storage that has turned off public network access and can't whitelist IP addresses from a local machine

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-vpn

I am moving some resources behind a virtual network to improve security. I have a storage account that has been disabled from public networks but that is connected to a virtual network. I have setup a CDN that has been able to connect to a blob container and display images stored there. At the moment, I can't connect to the blob container from my local machine using the Azure Storage Explorer or the Azure portal. I have tried setting up an Azure VPN Gateway using a point to site connection but I still receive the following error:

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation.> This storage account's 'Firewalls & virtual networks' settings may be blocking access to storage services. Try adding your client IP address to the firewall exceptions, or by allowing access from 'all networks' instead of 'selected networks'.

As a last resort, I can whitelist my IP address and everything works. However, there are other people that require access from their local machines and this is not a sustainable solution. Is there a setting that the VPN requires in order to connect to the storage account? Will this approach work if I move some Azure SQL databases to the same virtual network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are going to need a Private Endpoint - basically a NIC dedicated to each resource, or in the case of the storage account or similar resource, a specific service of the resource. Using these for storage accounts and Azure SQL is well-documented, they will work just fine with the Azure VPN gateway assuming your DNS is configured correctly. Mis-configuration of DNS is by far the most common issue with Private Endpoints. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview If you do decide to go Private Endpoint don't hesitate to ask any followup questions.

One point for you to consider - do you really need this to enhance security? For the storage account, you can disable key access and use identity-based access, and for Azure SQL you can accomplish basically the same thing by disabling local SQL authentication. There are at least two other negatives with private endpoints (1) they cost about $7/month per endpoint and they substantially complicate any infrastructure as code or CICD you are doing or may wish to do in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have disabled key access and moved to use identity based access but we have been requested to lock down our resources as much as possible. I have created a private endpoint for the storage account blob containers but I don't think I have setup the DNS correctly. I am running through the steps outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity. Do you have any other resources that may be of use in fixing this?

Comment: Your end client that needs to use the storage account is on the point side of a point to site VPN using an Azure Virtual Network gateway? If so, what is the DNS configuration of that client when it connects to Azure? To what does it resolve the storage account endpoint? You may need the Private Resolver here because I do not think you would be able to use Azure DNS directly from outside of Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-private-resolver-overview

Comment: As an intermediate troubleshooting step I would suggest setting up an Azure VM in the same vNet. If that works correctly then your base configuration is fine, it's just the over-vpn or whatever other remote connectivity method that is at issue.

Comment: I created a VM on the same VNet and I was able to access the blob container using the Azure portal. If I try that on my local machine I get an access denied error so the VNet appears to be working. What should I be looking at in relation to the VPN?

Comment: Your end goal is to get to where resolving the DNS name of the storage account on the device on the other end of the VPN results in a private IP address, specifically the one corresponding to the storage account. That is why the private DNS resolver is useful - something needs to resolve the name of the storage account using the private DNS zone - the resolver is the cloud native option but in hybrid environments this is done by a domain controller VM in the cloud using conditional forwarders in DNS - there are many different options. For local testing, you could even use hosts file.

Comment: This article seems to be exactly what you would need: https://luke.geek.nz/azure/azure-point-to-site-vpn-and-private-dns-resolver/

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a tutorial like that. I did read about the private DNS resolver before and I was hoping to find another approach that would be more affordable. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Oh wow, I did not realize the DNS resolver costs as much as it does. Any VM that can host a DNS server should do the trick, even Windows. But depending on the size of your environment you may just do well enough with the host file - it is a hacky approach but the private IPs should not need to change (unless you change vNet address space).

Comment: I must point out that making things more secure just because you can is not necessarily wisdom. And it has clear costs, in money and complexity. Is your org using M365? I would push back at least slightly with the argument that Entra is trusted for the security of that and should therefore be trusted for this too.

Comment: I am testing out approaches to make our system more secure based on Microsoft's Defender for Cloud's recommendations. I don't agree with this approach but I'm trying to see how much it is going to cost as we have a limited budget. Do you have a tutorial on using the host file?

Comment: Here you go, the first solution there is using host file. https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/testing-private-dns-resolution-over-a-p2s-vpn-using-azure-dns-private-resolver/

Comment: That linked worked for my purposes. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer, the points are helpful!